# AS2 replace Onpress to on keypress

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I am using a flash file as quiz game, based on AS2:

```
_root.next_btn.onPress = function() {
            timings();
            questno += 1;
            import mx.transitions.*;
            import mx.transitions.easing.*;
            TransitionManager.start(_root.quest_txt, {type:Fade, direction:Transition.IN, duration:1.5, easing:None.easeNone});
            _root.quest_txt.text = questions[questno-1];
            _root.opt_a.text = opt_aval[questno-1];
            _root.opt_b.text = opt_bval[questno-1];
            _root.opt_c.text = opt_cval[questno-1];
            _root.opt_d.text = opt_dval[questno-1];
            _root.ans_txt.text = ans_txtval[questno-1];
            _root.check_1.gotoAndStop(1);
            _root.check_2.gotoAndStop(1);
            _root.check_3.gotoAndStop(1);
            _root.check_4.gotoAndStop(1);
            _root.check_1.enabled = true;
            _root.check_2.enabled = true;
            _root.check_3.enabled = true;
            _root.check_4.enabled = true;
            _root.check_btn.enabled = true;
            _root.wrong_mc._visible = false;
            _root.right_mc._visible = false;
            _root.next_btn._visible = false;
            _root.correctansis._visible = false;
            _root.correctans_txt._visible = false;
            if (questno == questVal.length) {
                this._visible = false;
            }
            _root.quest_no.text = questno;
        };
```

i want to replace this code i guess
`_root.next_btn.onPress = function() {`
Instead of on Press i want to replace it with On Key Press ( keyboard for example, when i click  "a" )

you can find the file here : http://www.ffiles.com/flash/web_applications_and_data/quiz_programme_2501.html

Answer (score 0):

In AS2 you will need to create a listener object, attach that to the Key top level class and have that trigger your function. [AS2 Docs Reference Here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001133.html). Something like:

```
var keyboardListener:Object = new Object();
keyboardListener.onKeyDown = function()
{
    if(Key.getCode() == 65)     //Keycode for a
    {
        //Run all the functionality you want here...
    }
}

Key.addListener(keyboardListener:Object );
```